# Segfault when erasing from vector while in nested loops

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, erase

This is the code I'm running:

```
for(auto candidate = candidates.begin(); candidate != candidates.end();) {
    for(auto inst = candidate->sortedLoads.begin(); inst != candidate->sortedLoads.end(); inst++) {
        if(...) {
            candidate = candidates.erase(candidate);
            break;
        }

        else {
            candidate++;
        }
    }        
}
```

Running into a segfault with above. If I remove the inner for-loop the segfault goes away. Do you guys know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
You're incrementing your `candidate` variable from the outer loop in the inner loop, where nothing prevents him to exceed its upperbound `candidate != candidates.end()`. Add at least that condition to your inner loop as well. You'll end up with:

```
for(auto candidate = candidates.begin(); candidate != candidates.end();) {
    for(auto inst = candidate->sortedLoads.begin(); candidate != candidates.end() && inst != candidate->sortedLoads.end() ; inst++) {
        if(...) {
            candidate = candidates.erase(candidate);
            break;
        }

        else {
            candidate++;
        }
    }
}
```

But in general if you would increment/decrement (or whatever operation that changes value) a loop variable inside another loop, you need to repeat the first loop condition(where the variable is coming from) in the second loop (where it's being changed)!

Comment: Yup, just realized this when I was staring to make sure formatting was right. Thanks!

Comment: Real close, but missing a change of `inst` when  the `candidate` changes out from under it.

Comment: good point, I left that last simplification out. It was not correct for this context. I switched conditions in inner loop as well. Thanx @user4581301. Prasanna UV you'll have to be carefull

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

```
inst = candidate->sortedLoads.begin();
```

`inst` is an iterator to something inside `candidate`. If `candidate` is erased, to what does `inst` refer? No one knows.

Problem 2: Say you've merely incremented `candidate` and `inst` is still a valid reference.

```
inst != candidate->sortedLoads.end()
```

`inst` refers to an entry in the `sortedLoads` of the first `candidate` and being compared against the `end` of another `sortedLoads` in another `candidate`. The exit conditions will almost certainly not be met before badness occurs.

Problem 3: J.Baoby already covered: There is not test for overshooting the end of `candidate`s in the inner loop.

Don't have a good solution for you on this one. Recommend trying to untangle the logic between `inst` and `candidate` on this.

Comment: Is Problem 1 an issue even if I'm breaking from the inner loop on erase()? Problems 2 and 3 are logical flaws, agreed.

Comment: @PrasannaUV I missed the `break`. You should have that one beat.

Comment: You can solve problem 2 by adding an additional `break` when you increment your `candidate `. But that will mean your inner loop will make no sense... an if-else structure where in both cases the loop is breaked!! => no inner loop needed